# Ongoing confusion about ivars and properties in objective C

Tags: object-oriented, objective-c, variables, properties

After almost 8 months being in ios programming, I am again confused about the right approach. Maybe it is not the language but some OOP principle I am confused about. I don't know..

I was trying C# a few years back. There were fields (private variables, private data in an object), there were getters and setters (methods which exposed something to the world), and properties which was THE exposed thing. I liked the elegance of the solution, for example
there could be a class that would have a property called `DailyRevenue`...a float...but there was no private variable called `dailyRevenue`, there was only a field - an array of single transaction revenues... and the getter for `DailyRevenue` property calculated the revenue transparently.
If somehow the internals of daily revenue calculation would change, it would not affect somebody who consumed my `DailyRevenue` property in any way, since he would be shielded from getter implementation.

I understood that sometimes there was, and sometimes there wasn't a 1-1 relationship between fields and properties. Depending on the requirements. It seemed ok in my opinion. And that properties are THE way to access the data in object.

I know the difference betweeen private, protected, and public keyword.

Now lets get to Objective-C.

On what factor should I base my decision about making something only an ivar or making it as a property? Is the mental model the same as I describe above? I know that ivars are "protected" by default, not "private" as in C#.. But thats ok I think, no big deal for my present level of understanding the whole iOS development. The point is ivars are not accessible from outside (given I don't make them public.. but I won't).

The thing that clouds my clear understanding is that I can have `IBOutlets` from ivars. **Why am I seeing internal object data in the UI?** **Why is it ok?** On the other hand, if I make an `IBOutlet` from property, and I do not make it readonly, anybody can change it. **Is this ok too?**

Let's say I have a `ParseManager` object. This object would use a built in `Foundation` framework class called `NSXMLParser`. Obviously my `ParseManager` will utilize this `NSXMLParser`'s capabilities but will also do some additional work. Now my question is, **who should initialize this `NSXMLParser` object and in which way** should I make a reference to it from the `ParseManager` object, when there is a need to parse something.

**A) the `ParseManager`**

-**1)** in its default init method (possible here ivar  - or - ivar+ppty)

-**2)** with lazyloading in getter (required a ppty here)

**B) Some other object** - who will pass a reference to `NSXMLParser` object to the `ParseManager` object.

-**1)** in some custom initializer (`initWithParser:(NSXMLPArser *)parser`) when creating the `ParseManager` object..

A1 - the problem is, we create a parser and waste memory while it is not yet needed. However, we can be sure that all methods that are part of `ParserManager` object, can use the ivar safely, since it exists.
A2 - the problem is, the `NSXMLParser` is exposed to outside world, although it could be read-only. Would we want a parser to be exposed in some scenario?
B1 - this could maybe be useful when we would want to use more types of parsers.. I don't know...

I understand that architectural requirements and language is not the same. But clearly the two are in relation.

How to get out of that mess of my?

Please bear with me, I wasn't able to come up with a single ultimate question. And secondly, it's better to not scare me with some superadvanced newspeak that talks about some crazy internals (what the compiler does) and edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you're asking many questions, not one.

And half of the answers of these questions is the ever correct "**It depends**".

In general, exposing object ivars directly is discouraged if you're aiming for looser coupling (obviously). Although I think when it comes to IBOutlets it is an acceptable practice, since after all the Interface Builder is tasked with the creation of the object.

On the other hand, a readwrite property for an `NSInteger` makes little sense, unless you're doing something very funky, and you can easily use an ivar instead.

Once upon a time, in pre-ARC ages, there were some people, who advocated *always* using properties for objects, since then you don't need to care about `retain`/`release`. However now that ARC is widely used, this makes almost no difference and it is mostly a cosmetical thing.

A final piece of advice: aim for consistency project-wide.

EDIT: I'm not the greatest fan imaginable of Design Patterns, but it seems that most of your questions would find the best answer in this book.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as mentioned above, there're so many questions :)

First of all, you should read more about properties and the whole Objective-C principles. In modern Objective-C style you should not use ivars at all. Only properties with some very rare exceptions. For private properties there's some unusual trick: class extensions. You definitely should read about categories and extensions since they are very powerful and useful mechanics. You just keep your private properties and all outlets in the class extension and no one will see it outside your class implementation. But you'll be still able to access your outlets in Interface Builder! It's amazing solution I use everyday and feels good.

Now for your question about `ParserManager`. As said above, it depends. If you don't want the actual `NSXMLParser` be accessed directly outside the manager (you'd better don't :)), just leave it inside and create in the manager. I'd recommend to create it in the `init` method because of quite heavy and continuos initialization of such huge object. Yes, you're waste some memory for it much earlier you actually need it, but you'll get much faster access when the time's come.

Answer (score 0):

You *usually* have a property and a variable backing it. You keep the backing variable hidden. But it lets you do things like taking actions if a setter actually changes the property. Or for cached properties, you set the variable to nil and the getter stored the correct value on the first call. Or setters and getters read from a database and so on.

Sometimes you have properties like the center of a view that can be read by calculating the center from left and width, or where the setter moves the view so it’s center is where the setter wanted it.

Comment: I think a problem in explaining this is that C# isn't a particularly good language to demonstrate the distinction between fields and properties, because the syntax is designed to make properties look like fields, when actually they are methods. Indeed, the syntactic similarity means that swapping between using fields and properties is source-compatible, and explaining the binary incompatibility requires talking about much more complicated topics and scenarios.